# Core Plot NSDate Time Interval on Axis which excludes Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: core-plot, axis-labels, nstimeinterval

To assure time continuity, I convert NSDates of a time series into time interval, and use for scatterplot or bar chart. The problem now is that Saturdays and Sundays are also included in X axis scale.

I wonder if it is possible to excludes weekends from the axis scale, making Monday date a following day of Friday, while still sticking to the use of time interval.

I could use custom labeling, but my time series does not include all weekdays, and I still want all weekdays to be shown even if not include in the time series.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot plot ranges always cover a continuous range of values. To cut out the weekends, you'll need to define a mapping between dates and the linear time scale of the plot that excludes the weekend dates. The mapping should be defined both ways (date to plot value and plot value to date) so you can label the axis.